# typescript declare: what is the difference between `export function` and `export type .. lambda`?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript4.0

What is the difference between exports:

index.d.ts

```
declare module '@my/customs'{
    export function ModuleFactory(environment:any): any
}
```

and

```
declare module '@my/customs'{
     export type ModuleFactory = (environment: any) => any;
}
```

When I anotate function `ModuleFactory(environment){..}` only first works, when second return typescript error

> TS2693: "'ModuleFactory' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.",

I would understand the difference if you point me the TS "thing" that should be annotated with second option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda equivalent to the first file would be

```js
declare module '@my/customs'{
     type ModuleFactoryFn = (environment: any) => any;

     export const ModuleFactory: ModuleFactoryFn;
}
```